# Trying to calculate diff between Minimum value to every value in a cell

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, impala

I have two columns in table and I am trying to calculate diff between least performer to every cell in the column.

```
Column_a  column_B

abc       1
DEF       5
GHI       7
JKL       8
```

I am trying to get an output like below

```
abc    1   0
def    5   4
ghi    5   6
jkl    8   7
```

Column_c diff between each cell in column b to min(column b)

Comment: In output, ghi should 7    6, right?

Comment: Yes ,it's 7,6 ...My fault ..Thank you ...

Comment: script added to the ans section.

Comment: As SQL is orderless you should have a column which indicates the order and use ORDER BY on which is required as all given answers will not give stabile results.. Unless column b can be used for the order???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select column_a, column_b, (column_b - min(column_b) over ())
from t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SELECT Column_a , Column_b,
Column_b- (SELECT MIN(Column_b) FROM your_table) AS Column_c
FROM Your_table
```